# Vagrant "Waiting for VM to boot. This can take a few minutes" is slow

Tags: virtualbox, vagrant

I'm working on Chef recipes, and often need to test the full run-through with a clean box by destroying a VM and bringing it back up. However, this means I get this message in Vagrant/VirtualBox:

```
Waiting for VM to boot. This can take a few minutes.
```

very often. What are some steps I can take to make the boot faster?

I am aware this is an "opinion" question and would welcome some suggestions to make this more acceptable, besides breaking it into a bunch of small questions like "Will switching to an SSD make my VirtualBox boot faster? Will reducing the number of forwarded ports make my VirtualBox boot faster", etc.

Comment: Not specifically code related, more applicable to SuperUser :)

Answer (score 0):

I would go for using LXC containers instead of VirtualBox. That gives you much faster feedback cycle.

Here is [a nice introduction](http://fabiorehm.com/blog/2013/04/28/lxc-provider-for-vagrant/) to the [vagrant-lxc provider](https://github.com/fgrehm/vagrant-lxc).

You could set up a VirtualBox VM for Vagrant / Chef development with LXC containers (e.g. like [this dev-box](https://github.com/tknerr/dev-box/)). Then take this [sample-cookbook](https://github.com/tknerr/sample-toplevel-cookbook) and run either the [ChefSpec](https://github.com/sethvargo/chefspec) unit tests via `rake test` or the [kitchen-ci](http://kitchen.ci/) integration tests via `rake integration`. You will see that it's much faster with LXC than it is with VirtualBox (or any other full virtualization hypervisor).

Apart from that:

- yes, SSDs help a lot :-)
- use [vagrant-cachier](https://github.com/fgrehm/vagrant-cachier) which speeds up loads of other things via caching
- use a recent Vagrant version which uses Ruby 2.0+ (much faster than 1.9.3)
- don't always run a full integration test, some things can be caught via unit tests / chefspec already
- use SSH connection sharing and persistent connections
- etc...

As an another alternative you could also use [chef-runner](https://github.com/mlafeldt/chef-runner), which explicitly tries to solve the fast feedback problem